# Symfony - can't clear cache through command

Tags: php, symfony, caching, environment, homestead

I'm working on a vagrant machine (Homestead). In my Homestead.yml I have:

```
sites:
  - map: myproject.local
    to: /home/vagrant/projects/myproject/web
    type: symfony
```

I'm working with Symfony version 3.3 on PHP 7.1.2.

The problem is when I try to execute the command `php bin/console cache:clear` I'm getting the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
>     Failed to remove directory "/home/vagrant/projects/vkfilestore-code/var/cache/de~/pools": .

In my **AppKernel.php** I have:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
```

When I dump `$this->getEnvironment()` it says **dev**.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: remove the cache dir by yourself. Did you can clear the prod cache? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Virtual platform related issue.A simple workaround is to remove manually.

```
$ sudo rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Read more about this issue [app/console cache:clear problem](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19851)

Answer (score 1):

Most prpbably it is a permission issue. Give permission like

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/
```

This should solve your problem. If the problem still persist do :-

```
sudo rm -rf app/cache/
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/
```