# Symfony production cache creation trouble

Tags: symfony

I'm running a Symfony 3.2.6 app on a website since about one year. I'm making some changes these days, so I upload the new code and then run cache:clear command. I did this just 2 days ago and it was all right. I did it again today and I get this error when running cache:clear (actual path is a little bit obscured)

```
    php.CRITICAL: Fatal Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required 
 '/xxx/xxx/xxx/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SilCastDeepRedDeepRedBundleEntityDriver.php' (include_path='. ; ; Windows: \path1') {"exception":"
 [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 
0): Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required 
 '/xxx/xxx/xxx/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__SilCastDeepRedDeepRedBundleEntityDriver.php' (include_path='.\n;\n; Windows: \\path1') at  /xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209)"}
```

I even tried running cache:clear with --no-warmup and run then cache:warmup, but I get the same error during warmup.
If I take a look at the 'prod' directory in cache after the error, I see it doesn't contain any directory beyond 'pools': no doctrine, no assetic, no translations, no twig.
The 'Driver' entity class whose proxy looks not to be found has not been changed since many months.
Symfony Development environment works perfectly, both on my Windows 7 development laptop and on Linux production system.
The error I get shows up the same on both environments (Windows 7 and Linux, but on both only trying to build 'prod' cache; for 'dev' cache it's all right); this means it should not be something related to the server, some permission trouble or something like that. The matter looks to be inside the application code, but what can it be?
The question that was addressed as being possible the same is actually not. It talks about failing to remove a directory, while I never get that error

Comment: Rename prod folder inside cache directory and rebuild cache through cache command, But first check it on dev environment like running project with app_dev.php

Comment: Did you try remove `cache/prod` manually?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thanks for answering but as already wrote Development environment works perfectly. I already tried many times to build the cache, both having or not having an existing 'prod' dir. Always the same.

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev thanks to you as well. Yes I tried, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: You have to give grand to write and read `chmod -R 777 cache/prod`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony - can't clear cache through command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796710/symfony-cant-clear-cache-through-command)

Comment: Do someone think I would get the same error on Windows if it was permission related?

Comment: @habibun definetely not. That one has an error about failing to remove a directory. I don't get anything like that.

Comment: @gillo my last guess would be clear prod.log file under logs folder and then run cache command if it fails check the log file it should have some clue for this

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid anything. The only thing it shows up in log is the error I posted

Comment: Please confirm you are using bin/console cache:clear --env=prod after removing the var/cache/prod directory.

Comment: @Cerad yes of course

Comment: Consider rolling back your recent changes and trying again.  That will at least confirm that it is app source code problem and not something really out of the twilight zone.

Comment: @Cerad I tried even this but with no result. I cannot be 100% sure actually, as I rolled back the code manually, so something may have been left behind, even if I don't think so.    
I solved recreating the whole application from scratch, with a newer version of Symfony. This issue will remain a mystery.